# PyMC3 performance issues with No U-Turn Sampler (NUTS): less than 2 iterations per second with simple model

Tags: python, theano, pymc3

I am trying to understand what is the problem with the following code:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import theano as t

X = t.shared(train_new)
features = list(map(str, range(train_new.shape[1])))
with pm.Model() as logistic_model:
    glm = pm.glm.GLM(X, targets, labels=features,
                     intercept=False, family='binomial')
    trace = pm.sample(3000, tune=3000, jobs=-1)
```

The dataset is by no means big: its shape is `(891, 13)`. Here is what I concluded on my own:

- the problem is surely not the hardware because the performance is the same both on my laptop and on a c4.2xlarge AWS instance;
- it cannot be `theano.shared` because if I remove it the performance is again the same;
- the problem does not appear to be in `pymc3.glm.GLM` because when I manually build the model (which is probably simpler than the one in `GLM`) the performance is just as terrible:

  ```
  with pm.Model() as logistic_model:
      invlogit = lambda x: 1 / (1 + pm.math.exp(-x))
      σ = pm.HalfCauchy('σ', beta=2)
      β = pm.Normal('β', 0, sd=σ, shape=X.get_value().shape[1])
      π = invlogit(tt.dot(X, β))
      likelihood = pm.Bernoulli('likelihood', π, observed=targets)
  ```

It starts at around `200 it/s` and the quickly falls to `5 it/s`. After half sampling, it decreases further to around `2 it/s`. This is a serious problem, as the model barely converges with a couple of thousands of samplings. I need to perform many more samples than what this situation currently allows.

This is the log:

```
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using jitter+adapt_diag...
 99%|█████████▊| 5923/6000 [50:00<00:39,  1.97it/s]
```

I tried with `pm.Metropolis()` as step, and it was a bit faster but it didn't converge.

**MWE**: a file with a minimal working example showing the issue and the data is here:
https://gist.github.com/rubik/74ddad91317b4d366d3879e031e03396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-centered version of the model should work much better:

```
β_raw = pm.Normal('β_raw', 0, sd=1, shape=X.get_value().shape[1])
β = pm.Deterministic('β', β_raw * σ)
```

Usually your first impulse if the effective sample size is small shouldn't be to just increase the number of samples, but to try and play with the parametrization a bit.

Also, you can use `tt.nnet.sigmoid` instead of your custom invlogit, that might be faster/more stable.

Comment: Thank you! I had read elsewhere that in these cases it's better to offset the parametrization, but I couldn't make it work. With your version I see an instant 70x improvements with NUTS.

Comment: Hi, I'm running into performance problems with a similar setup on a large dataset and am unsure if it's related to this. Why do you need to beta * sigma?